# How to deserialize nested object in java SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I have the following xml and i want to parse it with simpleXML.

```
<programme start="20161107190000 GMT+04:00" stop="20161107200000 GMT+04:00" channel="001">
    <title lang="en_GB">Foo</title>
    <desc lang="en_GB">Foobarbaz</desc>
</programme>
<programme start="20161107200000 GMT+04:00" stop="20161107203000 GMT+04:00" channel="001">
    <title lang="en_GB">JLS</title>
    <desc lang="en_GB">The Java Language Specification</desc>
</programme>
```

having the following

```
@Root
public class Programme {

    @Attribute(name = "channel", required = false)
    private String channel;

    @Attribute(name = "start", required = false)
    private String start;

    @Attribute(name = "stop", required = false)
    private String stop;

    @Element(name = "title", required = false)
    private Title title;

    @Element(name = "desc", required = false)
    private String desc;

    public Programme(String channel, String start, String stop, String title, String desc) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    public void setStop(String stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    public Title getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Root(name = "title")
    public class Title {

        @Attribute
        private String lang;

        private String text;

        public Title(String lang, String text) {
            this.lang = lang;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getLang() {
            return lang;
        }

        public void setLang(String lang) {
            this.lang = lang;
        }

        @Text
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Text
        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

}
```

gives me the error `org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Can not construct inner class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of things to be careful about.

1) if you have nested class for Attributes in inner Elements the nested class must be `static`.

2) defining variable for inner class must annotate as follows

```
@Element(name = "title", type = Title.class, required = false)
private Title title;
```

3) inside constructor they should instantiate an empty class

```
this.title = new Title();
```

This is a full working version:

```
@Root
public class Programme {


    @Attribute(name = "channel", required = false)
    private final String channel;

    @Attribute(name = "start", required = false)
    private final String start;

    @Attribute(name = "stop", required = false)
    private final String stop;


    @Element(name = "title", type = Title.class, required = false)
    private Title title;

    @Element(name = "desc", type = Desc.class, required = false)
    private Desc desc;

    public Programme(
            @Attribute(name = "channel") String channel,
            @Attribute(name = "start") String start,
            @Attribute(name = "stop") String stop
    ) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
        this.title = new Title();
        this.desc = new Desc();
    }

    public Title getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Desc getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(Desc desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


    @Root(name = "title")
    public static class Title {
        public String text;
        @Attribute(name = "lang")
        private String lang;

        @Text
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Text
        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getLang() {
            return lang;
        }
    }

    @Root(name = "desc")
    public static class Desc {
        public String text;
        @Attribute(name = "lang")
        private String lang;

        @Text
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Text
        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getLang() {
            return lang;
        }
    }

}
```